# Creating a scalable database for android app | cloud hosted

Tags: android, cloud, google-cloud-storage, cloud-hosting, android-database

I am working to launch an app which in future will store huge number of users and there profile information.

But I Wanted to start small to pre-test my app idea , so what will be the options for hosting database which are cost effective initially and scalable in future , and easy to integrate too.

Many thanks for your inputs

Comment: what kind of research is needed here when i am seeking for solution ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit of a freak in that I use Postgresql. I have a database with millions of users and have 10 to 30 update transactions per second. I have found the n1-standard-8 (8 vCPU, 30 GB memory) machine with SSD disk to be a real screamer.

If you want to start out small, Postgresql works just fine too. It scales really well. I'm sure MySQL would be well suited to the task as well.

The key metric to handle high transaction rates is to have lots of memory and fast storage. The SSD option with GCE is quite up to the task.

Postgresql is open source and free to use.

Comment: thanks for this john, will Postgresql support spatial queries well ?, as i want to play around with spatial queries ?

Comment: I just viewed few blogs referring me to parse.com API for storing and retrieving geolocations data well ?....not sure how I can conclude between mysql, postgresql , google cloud sql , parse...and other options being on plate...

Comment: Yes, Postgresql supports a limited set of spatial queries. If you want a full set of amazing spatial functions, add the Postgresql extension PostGIS. That add on can do pretty much anything. I suggest reading up on the topic. It's pretty cool.